# gradient Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard-product

I am seeking to compute the following:

$\nabla ( \mathbf{1}^T f(X) )$

Where:

$\mathbf{1}^T = (1 , \ldots , 1)$ an $1 \times n$ vector.

$f(X)= (A*X) \circ (B*X)$

$A$ and $B$: $n \times n$ matrices

$X$: $n \times 1$ vector

$\circ$ the Hadamard or element wise product

$*$ matrix product.

I read the following rule $d(X \circ Y) = d(X) \circ Y + d(Y) \circ X$

But in the above I have a mixture of matrix and element wise product (dimensions are consistent at the end $\mathbf{1}^T f(X) $ is of size $1 \times 1$)

Comment: Prove that your function equals $x^TA^TBx$ and take it from there.

Comment: thank you very much I worked it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote the elementwise/Hadamard and inner/Frobenius products respectively as 
$$\eqalign{
 A &= B\circ C \cr
 \alpha &= B:C = {\rm tr}(B^TC) \cr
}$$
Recall that these products are commutative, and mutually commutative
$$\eqalign{
 A\circ B &= B\circ A \cr
 A:B &= B:A \cr
 A:B\circ C &= A\circ B:C \cr
}$$ and that the matrix of all ones is the identity element for the Hadamard product. Note that the matrices $(A,B,C)$ must have the same shape for these products to make sense.

Your scalar function can be written as
$$\eqalign{
y 
 &= 1:f \cr
 &= 1:(Ax)\circ(Bx) \cr
 &= Ax:Bx \cr
}$$
Whosee differential and gradient are 
$$\eqalign{
dy
 &= A\,dx:Bx + Ax:B\,dx \cr
 &= Bx:A\,dx + Ax:B\,dx \cr
 &= (A^TB + B^TA)\,x:dx \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} 
 &= (A^TB + B^TA)\,x \cr\cr
}$$
(Note that I've used juxtaposition rather than $*$ for the ordinary matrix product.)